# How To Make Flash Button of PNG Visible Area?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to know if there's a way in ActionScript 3 to load a PNG image and make some sort of button or sensible area applicable only for the visible area of that PNG??

Maybe there's a simple way to define a polygonal area on execution time, I mean, dynamically and make it sensible to mouse events??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the non-transparent area of the PNG to be the clickable area. This is a bit tricky, but luckily someone figured it out already. Use this ActionScript utility class called InteractivePNG.

http://blog.mosessupposes.com/?p=40

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

- Load the PNG image.
- Add it into sprite A.
- Add the polygonal structure into the sprite (added on top of PNG)
- Add it into a sprite B.
- Add an event listener to the polygonal sprite B.
- Add the sprite B into A.

Comment: will sprite B alpha is set to zero ??

Comment: If the polygonal area needs to be hidden, then set it to 0, else alpha need not be set.

Answer (score 1):

just set mouse events on your image file, essentially turning it into a button, and then draw and set a mask over the "visible area" of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest method is :
In the MouseEvent handler, detect the mouse position whether on the non-transparent area. 
If YES, go ahead the click logic. Otherwise, ignore it.

And the most accurate mothed is:
Use the Bezier curve to draw the exactly-fit shape as the clickable area.
But I think this method is too complex, and costs too much cpu.